# Python3: Convert path to list of folders and a possible file

Tags: python, python-3.x, path, cross-platform

How do I convert a path like `r'C:\Users\usern\Documents\file.txt'` into a list like `['C:', 'Users', 'usern', 'Documents', 'file.txt']`? I'd like it to work cross-platform, on Windows regardless on whether the path is given with forward slashes or backslashes or with a mixture of both, and regardless on whether the input string ends with a slash or not (i.e., no empty strings at the end for inputs like `'C:\\Users\\usern\\Documents\\'`).

To my best knowledge, the following should work on Windows, Mac and Linux:

```
import sys

def path_to_list(s):
    if sys.platform == 'win32':
        return s.replace('\\', '/').rstrip('/').split('/')
    else:
        return s.rstrip('/').split('/')
```

but I'm not sure if that works on *other* platforms where Python can be run, nor if this solution is very Pythonic for even these common platforms.

Problems could arise at least in the following cases:

1. if some platform allows an empty string to be a filename or a folder name,
2. if there exists a platform other than Windows which doesn't allow backslashes in filenames
3. if there exists *any* platform that does *not* allow the forward slash (`/`) as file-folder separator
4. if there exists *any* platform that allows characters other than the backslash (`\`) or forward slash (`/`) as file-folder separator

but I'm not sure if platforms like those exist and if so, does Python even run on them (if it doesn't no problem would be caused then)?

By the way, you *cannot* use `if '\\' in __file__: ...` (as a replacement for `if sys.platform == 'win32'` in the code block) to check if backslashes are allowed because, for some reason, `__file__` returns the path to the current script with forward slashes *even on Windows*. And it probably wouldn't be a good way to do this even if this wasn't the case.

Comment: You should use `os.sep` and take a look at [`os.path.split`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/os.path.html#os.path.split)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make use of [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html), specifically the [`parts`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#accessing-individual-parts) method, like so:

```py
from pathlib import Path

myPath = Path(r"C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.exe")
print(list(myPath.parts))
```

Returns `['C:\\', 'Program Files', 'CMake', 'bin', 'cmake.exe']`

### Edit

You can join the path back together like so

```py
newPath = Path(*myPath.parts)
print(newPath)
```

Returns `C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.exe`

Comment: In order to join them back, you'd need to remove the backslash at the end of `'C:\\'`, so I guess `[w.strip(os.sep) for w in myPath.parts]` would do it, probably cross-platform as `Path(r"C:/Program Files/CMake/bin/cmake.exe/").parts` also returns a tuple with `'C:\\'` as its first element (so no `...w.strip(os.sep + '/')...` necessary)?

Comment: @hilssu I've edited my answer with an example of how you can join them back together